# UnitTesting IonicPlatform and ngcordova Plugin

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine, ngcordova

Hey i'm currently trying to learn how to write UnitTests for ionic classes and cant find any good tutorials for this specific task of writing tests with ngCordova-mocks in combination with the ionicPlatform.ready() event.

Hope to find some help. Here is my working example of the Code to test

```
 module.exports = function(app) {
    function service($ionicPlatform, $cordovaGeolocation) {
        var getPosition = function() {
            return $ionicPlatform.ready()
                .then(function() {
                    return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition({timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
                })
        };
        return {
            getPosition: getPosition
        };
    }
    service.$inject = ['$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaGeolocation'];
    app.factory(app.name + '.' + servicename, service);
};
```